# Promise as a part of state in redux

Tags: redux, reswift

I have a situation when it would be really convenient to have a promise object as a part of the state. In short - there is a state which contains all the info which user gave in the question-answer mode and after some answer it would be nice to send a call, result of which will be needed after several more questions:

```
Q1 -> Q2 -> Q3 - -> Q4 - - -> Q5 -> Q6 -> Q7 
                 \ - - Call to API - - /
```

Before Q7 I need to check result of call after Q3. It would be really easy to do with promise as a part of the state and then just subscribe to result.
But I have inner feeling that it should not happen. Is it ok to do it this way?

I don't think that my code will help to understand, so feel free to just ask questions if it's not clear.

Comment: You can implement it into your action container , I dont see any issue with that

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif, do you mean action creator?

Comment: yes , implement all the logic in your action creator

Comment: I have Q3 after which I want to send a request, basically, it's a moment when I have promise. I don't understand how I can access this promise from Q7 with action creator.

Comment: all these Q4, Q5, Q6 will be some different functions somewhere in my flow. they will accept user input and send some actions as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that because serializing your state would not be possible anymore. How much of a problem that is, not sure, it might only break the devtools or some persistence/hydration library you are using or will use. But to stay true to redux and its simplicity, reduce your scenario to a single truth:

- Is the current question past Q3 but still before Q7? I imagine a selector could determine that because the current question is surely part of the state already.
- Has a request been made to fetch the data?

Based on that you send the request:

```
if (currentQuestion > 3 && currentQuestion < 7 && !isDataRequested) {
    dispatch(callToApi()); // this sets isDataRequested to true.
}
```

This will work **with** persisting and hydrating the state.

Comment: so basically, you advise having kind-of `promiseState` without promise itself. as `isDataRequested` is not enough for me. I need also to know if it failed and if it completed

Comment: just to make my situation a bit more clear, I have this `answer-results` in different sub-reducers. it looks like `store.dispatch(setCustomer(customer))` -> `func customerReducer(state, action) {//return new state with customer}` and more things like that. I hope it's clear :)

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko You can add the result of the api call to the condition then. `!isDataRequested && !success` (however success is determined). If you want to retry on failure it gets a bit more complicated, but same with an actual promise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [redux-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise) middleware, Your actions will return you promise if that action is completed, in-flight or failed. So you can easily manage questions and make call exactly at the right time you needed based on the promise. I have a sample example in my [github](https://github.com/alowsarwar/React_redux_promise_example) account which shall explain how to use it. Let know if you find it useful.

Below is suedo code

**Action controller**

```
export const action_CALL = () => {
  return {
    type: SOME_CALL,
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let wait = setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('DUMMY ... Few questions answered in x mins');
              }, 2000)
    }),
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export const countReducer = typeToReducer({
  [SOME_CALL]: {
    PENDING: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      answered: false,
    }),
    REJECTED: (state) => ({
      ...state,
      answered: false,
    }),
    FULFILLED: (state, action) => ({
      answered: true,
      callResponse: action.payload,
    })
  }
}, initState);
```

This approach will give you fine-grained control.

Comment: That does not address his problem at all.